# Disabling Directory redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, redirection

While I understand that this is a minor issue, I have wondered whether it is possible to disable redirects on directory urls in Apache2.

Currently, when connectiong to `http://localhost/cgi`, apache2 would redirect to `http://localhost/cgi/`, since `$WEBROOT/cgi` is a directory:

```
$ curl --head http://localhost/cgi
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 20 May 2011 05:01:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://localhost/cgi/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The reason I ask is because of a flaky connection to my webserver, where it usually takes an arguably long time to connect. I'd like to avoid unnecessary requests if possible.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour, so when connecting to `http://localhost/cgi` Apache would not attempt to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it off with the DirectorySlash directive in your config.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: Neat, although the security warning is kind of a party pooper (also I can't upvote due to lack of reputation) :(